# is zip function in the standard sml basis library?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am trying to implement a function that creates a list from two int lists to form pairs. But when I try to run zip, it tells me that this is an unbound variable. Is there any other function which does the same job in the library or some definition of zip with using the folding procedures?

Answer (score 5):

Try `ListPair.zip` or `ListPair.zipEq`. See also the [specification of the ListPair structure](http://standardml.org/Basis/list-pair.html#LIST_PAIR:SIG:SPEC) in the standard basis library.